# Why does using a django BooleanField in models.py cause a TypeError?

Tags: python, django, function, class

I'm creating a model for a todo list program. Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Todo(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

When I try to run `python manage.py migrate` after I make migrations, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bool'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the Boolean Field. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Here's the entire error that I got:

```
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in 
    execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 233, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 821, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Users/thuitema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2262, in get_db_prep_value
    return connection.Database.Binary(value)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bool'
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire stack trace, not just the final line?

Comment: I added the entire error to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
File "/Users/xxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2262, in get_db_prep_value
    return connection.Database.Binary(value)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bool'
```

The last two lines of your error log suggest that the model was originally built with the `models.BinaryField()` field type which would throw this type error with `default=False`. Rebuilding and running the migration with the `models.BooleanField(default=False)` line you already have above should solve it:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```